# Python: Iterating over loops

Tags: python, loops, tree, cartesian-product

I am not being able to generalize the following code for arbitrary lengths of `indeces`:

```
sol = 0
for f_2 in F_2:
        if f_2 in A[0]:
            fac1 = f(f_2,indeces[0])
            for f_1 in F_1:
                if f_1 in A[0][f_2][0]:
                    fac2 = f(f_1,indeces[1])
                    for f_0 in F_0:
                        if f_0 in A[0][f_2][0][f_1][0]:
                            sol += (float(A[0][f_2][0][f_1][0][f_0])/A[0][f_2][0][f_1][1])*fac1*fac2*f_(indeces[-1],f_0)
```

Maybe someone has an idea. In principle the problem is to iterate over loops. `A` is a tree structure with lists `[dict,int]` as nodes.

Comment: Could you provide a complete working example? It's not clear exactly what `f`, `F_0`, `F_1`, `F_2`, `A` and `indeces` are supposed to be.

Comment: Recursion is generally good for walking a tree structure of an arbitrary (but relatively small finite) depth; but I've no idea how that code is supposed to utilize such a values of a walk (nor do I feel like trying to unravel it). Providing sample input/output wouldn't hurt.

Comment: I believe you have two typos: 1) the argument for your `float()` is `...[f_0]`, which is a sub-node, shouldn't that be a number? I guess there is a `[1]` missing at the end. 2) towards the end of the last line, you use `f_()`, should that be `f()` or is that an other function?

Answer (score 1):

Your code only started making sense to me after I replaced `...[0]` with `.children` and `...[1]` with `.node_val`, which would happen if you were using a proper `Node` object with attributes `children` and `node_val`, instead of a list:

```
sol = 0
for f_2 in F_2:
    if f_2 in A.children:
        fac1 = f(f_2,indeces[0])
        for f_1 in F_1:
            if f_1 in A.children[f_2].children:
                fac2 = f(f_1,indeces[1])
                for f_0 in F_0:
                    if f_0 in A.children[f_2].children[f_1].children:
                        sol +=(float(A.children[f_2].children[f_1].children[f_0])
                                    /A.children[f_2].children[f_1].node_val)
                                    *fac1*fac2*f_(indeces[-1],f_0)
```

What you probably need is a recursive solution, something similar to this (obviously untested):

```
def recursive(F, indeces, node):
    assert len(F) == len(indeces)
    children = node[0]
    node_val = node[1]
    total = 0
    if len F > 1: # do recursive call
        for child_key in F[0]:
            if child_key in children:
                fac = f(child_key, indeces[0])
                total += fac * recursive(F[1:], indeces[1:], children[child_key])
    else: # only 1 item left
        for child_key in F[0]:
            if child_key in children:
                fac = f_(indeces[0], child_key)
                total += fac * (float(children[child_key]xx) / node_val)
    return total

F_X = [F_2, F_1, F_0]
ind = [i0, i1, i2]

result = recursive(F_X, ind, A)
```

The `xx` refers to my comment to your question, it seems that the argument of your `float()` is a node, while I would have expected a number (`node_val`?).

Comment: I was trying to get an interative solution, but I guess with such a small depth, recursive is fine. Actually there are 4 options: (1) implement all cases, because len(indeces) is practically in {2,3,4}, (2) recursive depth-first tree traversal, (3) iterative depth-first tree traversal, (4) a function that writes me a function once the parameter that determines len(indeces) is set. To be honest for now I just used (1) but I am still exited to get a good (2) or (3).

Answer (score 1):

Quickly, here is an implementation proposal

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, children={}, integer=0):
        self.dictionary = children
        self.integer    = integer

    @property
    def children(self):
        return self.dictionary


class Tree(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Node()

    def compute_your_thing(self, FF, indeces):
        """
        Assuming FF is a list of lists such that
            FF[0] = [f_00, f_01, f_02, ...]
            FF[1] = [f_10, f_11, f_12, ...]
            FF[2] = [f_20, f_21, f_22, ...]
            ...
            FF[len(indeces)]
        """
        # Generalize for any indeces length
        indeces_level = len(indeces)
        level = 0
        fac = []
        sol = 0

        def lookup(node, F):
            for f in F:
                if f in node.children:
                    new_node = node.children[f]
                    level += 1
                    if level == indeces_level:
                        # We have reached the depth defined by the length of indeces
                        sol += float(new_node.integer/node.integer) * times(fac) * foo(indeces[-1], f)
                    else :
                        fac.append(foo(f, indeces[level]))
                        return lookup(new_node, FF[indeces_level - level])

        # Use the nested loop to compute your thing recursively
        lookup(root, FF[indeces_level])
        return sol


# Utilities
def times(fac):
    result = 1
    for f in fac:
        result *= fac

    return result

def foo(ind, f):
    # I don't know what you do with this function
    pass
```

Hope this helps.